# c# Finding a string from a list that contains the text box text

Tags: c#, winforms, list, flowlayoutpanel

I'm trying to search for a string in a list that contains the text box's text. Then when it finds the record, adds it to a flow layout panel. It doesn't seem to be working properly.

I have 3 employees:

- Richard Jacobs
- Olivia Mularczyk
- Jess Mularczyk

All employees are added to the EmployeeList.

[GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JW5TZ.png)

When I type 'R' into the text box, only Richard shows up which is good! But when I type in 'Ri' it doesn't show up. Also When I type in 'O' or 'Olivia' that employee doesn't show up either!

Code:

```
if (EmployeeTb.Text != string.Empty)
{
    ResultsFLP.Controls.Clear();

    foreach (Cerealto.Classes.Employee Employee in Cerealto.Classes.Employees.EmployeeList)
    {
        if (Employee.firstName.Contains(EmployeeTb.Text))
        {
            ESR = new EmployeeSearchResultUC(Employee.employeeID, Employee.firstName + " " + Employee.lastName);
            ResultsFLP.Controls.Add(ESR);
        }
    }
}
else
{
    ResultsFLP.Controls.Clear();

    foreach (Cerealto.Classes.Employee Employee in Cerealto.Classes.Employees.EmployeeList)
    {
        ESR = new EmployeeSearchResultUC(Employee.employeeID, Employee.firstName + " " + Employee.lastName);
        ResultsFLP.Controls.Add(ESR);
    }
}
```

I hope you guys can help! :D

Comment: I don't have much to add in the way of why its not working.  I just wanted to point out that maybe you should look at your logic again, like really look at it to understand what its doing.  You may find that there are a lot of redundancies...

Comment: I've looked over and over, I really don't understand why it isn't working tbh. Thanks anyway! :D

Comment: Not that it's not working, but your logic is a bit off and you have opened up for some potential simple bugs (assuming your code you posted isn't omitting anything).  Check this [codeshare](https://codeshare.io/aYAnvb) I made with some notes.

Comment: Thanks for the comment

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If i understood your intentions properly,

a. you can use [Lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) its not a bad practice to learn this days.

b. notice my comment about your logic.
 
c. also use `ToLower()` if you want to search without considering if the user enters small letter or capital letter (can produce the problem you are presenting in that question) "Ri" is not "rI" and "RI" is not "ri" etc..

```
if (EmployeeTb.Text != string.Empty)
{
    ResultsFLP.Controls.Clear(); 
    var emp = Cerealto.Classes.Employees.EmployeeList.AsEnumerable().Where(x=> (x.firstName+ " " + x.lastName).ToLower().Contains(EmployeeTb.Text.ToString().ToLower().Trim())).Select(e=>e).ToList();

    if(emp != null)
    {
        foreach(Cerealto.Classes.Employee Employee e in emp)
        {
             ESR = new EmployeeSearchResultUC(e.employeeID, e.firstName + " " + e.lastName);
             ResultsFLP.Controls.Add(ESR);
        }
    }
}
else
{
    // there is no results here clear everything or make no change (dont use the line ResultsFLP.Controls.Clear(); / load all employees again)
    ResultsFLP.Controls.Clear();
}
```

Comment: This is not a very good solution.  You end up iterating over the collection multiple times, you do not account for the OP's logic of adding all employees to controls if the textbox is empty.

Comment: @ maccettura obsessively i have noticed that , but why you would want to show all employees in a search container if nothing was found?, i made a comment on that inside the else condition.

Comment: Although I completely understand your confusion with displaying all the records, it is not up to us to question the OP's business requirements.  Your code does not replicate the OP's logic and it introduces performance issues.  You will likely want to re-visit your answer.

Comment: Sorry for the comments but it only works now if you don't type in the first letter! 'ichard' works 'richard' doesn't haha

Comment: I am not near my computer are you using ToLower()?

Comment: Yeah I have, the employee first name is lower and it works! Just got to try and figure out how to search for the last name

Comment: In a short time I will be able to update my answer also with last name (still not with my pc)

Comment: @ Richard Jacobs please see my update in order to search for first name and last name together.